# Clearing url search params upon unmount

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react router for routing in my app, and I can't seem to figure out how to use the `useSearchParams` hook in order to clear the search params upon navigating to a new route.

I've tried to utilize the cleanup function of `useEffect` in order to clean up the search params, but it seems to navigate to the previous route upon exiting the component.

The basic code is something like the following:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Outlet, Link, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Basic Example</h1>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum
      </p>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/nothing-here">Nothing Here</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <hr />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

function About() {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      searchParams.delete("someParam")
      setSearchParams(searchParams);  // This will route back to the `About` component
    }
  }, setSearchParams)

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I made a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bha8hk?file=src/App.tsx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to overcome this issue by using the following browser native code, though it would still be nice if a more "react-router"-y solution was possible:

```js
useEffect(() => () => {
    const url = new URL(window.location);
    url.searchParams.remove('key');
    window.history.replaceState(null, '', url.toString());
})
```